# Email notification when changes are made to specific data in Google sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a general script that will send email notification of changes made to a live roster in Google sheets and have set up a trigger for the event to occur 'On change'. All data in the sheet is retrieved via IMPORTRANGE. This script is performing as expected, however I wish to make a couple of changes that am not sure how to go about. Here is a sample sheet: [link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LjELgjsFjxIrqsk-ROEtRkOjL9987VtcCoc0A8X-8DE/edit?usp=sharing)

1. Wish to only send email notification when changes concern the name 'Craig'. For example my name is either added or taken off a rostered day. The script currently sends emails for all changes made across the sheet.
2. ID the row that this change occurs so as to reference the date and venue in the email body.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Full script:

```
function onEdit() {

    var getProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

    var lenProp = getProps.getProperty('Len');

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster');

    var data = sheet.getRange('E4:ACB562').getValues().toString().length;

    if (data != lenProp) {
        getProps.setProperty('Len', data );
        MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', 'Changes have been made to your live roster', 'Previous value: ' + lenProp + ' New value: ' + data);
    }
}
```

New revised script:

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var value = range.getValue();
  if (value == "Craig" || (e.oldValue == "Craig" && value == "")) {
    var rowNumber = range.getRow(); // You can retrieve the row number of the editor cell.
    console.log(rowNumber)
    var [colA, colB] = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, 2).getValues()[0];

    var getProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var lenProp = getProps.getProperty('Len');
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster_LIVE');
    var data = sheet.getRange('E4:ACB562').getValues().toString().length;
    if (data != lenProp) {
      getProps.setProperty('Len', data);
      MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', 'Changes have been made to your roster!', 'Your live roster has been edited. These changes concern ' + colB + ' on ' + colA);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: About `Wish to only send email notification when changes concern the name 'Craig'.` and your script, I thought that to know your Spreadsheet will help to think of the solution. But I cannot open your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: Strange, it is a public link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LjELgjsFjxIrqsk-ROEtRkOjL9987VtcCoc0A8X-8DE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I could confirm that it can be opened. And, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to send an email using OnEdit trigger when the value of `Craig` is put to a cell.
- You want to retrieve the edited row number.
- You want to run the script when the value of `Craig` is removed.

#### Modification points:

- From `I have a general script that will send email notification of changes made to a live roster in Google sheets and have set up a trigger for the event to occur 'On change'.`, I understood that you are using the installable OnChange trigger. If it's so, in your situation, I would like to recommend to use the installable OnEdit trigger.
- And, when I saw your script, the function name is `onEdit`. If the installable OnEdit trigger installs to `onEdit`, when a cell is edited, `onEdit` is run 2 times by the simple trigger and the installable trigger with the asynchronous process. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5) So, please rename the function name from `onEdit` to other and reinstall the installable OnEdit trigger to the renamed function name.
- In order to retrieve the row number of the edited cell, you can use the event object.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

After the script was modified, please install the OnEdit trigger to the function of `installedOnEdit`. In this script, when you put the value of `Craig` to a cell, the script below the if statement is run.

From:

```
function onEdit() {

    var getProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

    var lenProp = getProps.getProperty('Len');

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster');

    var data = sheet.getRange('E4:ACB562').getValues().toString().length;

    if (data != lenProp) {
        getProps.setProperty('Len', data );
        MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', 'Changes have been made to your live roster', 'Previous value: ' + lenProp + ' New value: ' + data);
    }
}
```

To:

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var value = range.getValue();
  if (value == "Craig" || (e.oldValue == "Craig" && value == "")) {
    var rowNumber = range.getRow(); // You can retrieve the row number of the editor cell.
    console.log(rowNumber)

    var getProps = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
    var lenProp = getProps.getProperty('Len');
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Roster');
    var data = sheet.getRange('E4:ACB562').getValues().toString().length;
    if (data != lenProp) {
      getProps.setProperty('Len', data);
      MailApp.sendEmail('email@gmail.com', 'Changes have been made to your live roster', 'Previous value: ' + lenProp + ' New value: ' + data);
    }
  }
}
```

- In this modified script, when the value of `Craig` is put to a cell, the script below the if statement is run. If you want to also check the column and row, please tell me.

#### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help. I have made the changes above along with creating a new OnEdit trigger. The script is now giving the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
installedOnEdit @ EmailChanges.gs:3

Comment: also.... I want want to send an email using OnEdit trigger when the value of Craig is put to a cell or removed.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your situation, how did you run the script? From your error message of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined installedOnEdit @ EmailChanges.gs:3`, when the function of `installedOnEdit` is run with the script editor, such error occurs. If my understanding of your situation is correct, when a value of `Craig` is put to a cell, what result will you obtain? If my understanding is not correct, can you provide the detail flow for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Craig About your replying of `also.... I want want to send an email using OnEdit trigger when the value of Craig is put to a cell or removed.`, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? When I tested the modified script, when the cell value of `Craig` is put or removed, I could confirm that the script worked. But if in your environment, the script was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Thanks again, yes the error was due to running the script from script editor. Can you please confirm that I should be running the trigger onEdit and not OnChange? This sheet does not get edited, but rather changes occur through IMPORTRANGE.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. I understood that the error of `Cannot read property 'range' of undefined` was due to the method for executing the script. About the reason I proposed to use OnEdit, when OnEdit is used, the range object and `oldValue` are included in the event object. I thought that these values are important for your situation. At OnChange, unfortunately, those are not included in the event object. So I proposed to use OnEdit. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This updated script is working great. Just one last silly question.... how do I reference the variable rowNumber in the email body text? Please see revised script above.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question of `how do I reference the variable rowNumber in the email body text?`. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about it, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your new question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. Your English is fine and sorry for not being clearer. Your new suggested script retrieves the row number of the cell that has been edited as a variable? I want the email body to read: 'Your live roster has been edited. These changes concern (Venue) on (Date).' Please see my updated post with 'New revised script'. I am trying to use the variable 'rowNumber' to retrieve the data in columns A & B of the edited row.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. About `Your new suggested script retrieves the row number of the cell that has been edited as a variable?`, it's yes. About `I am trying to use the variable 'rowNumber' to retrieve the data in columns A & B of the edited row.`, in this case, for my 2nd script, please put `var [colA, colB] = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, 2).getValues()[0];` just after the line of `var rowNumber = range.getRow();`. By this, `colA` and `colB` are the values from the columns "A" and "B" of the edited row, respectively. If this was not the result you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: Hello, just getting a Apps Script notification error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined. Please see the full script titled 'New revised script' above. Thanks again.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I have to apologize. In my sample script, `sheet` is not declared. I forgot it. This is the reason of your current issue. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. In that case, please modify `var [colA, colB] = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, 2).getValues()[0];` to `var [colA, colB] = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, 2).getValues()[0];` and test it again.

Comment: Success! Thanks, you are brilliant. One last thing... I would like to edit date formatting. to "NZ", "EEE MMM dd". Where in the script would I place this? The date comes from colA. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, it already prints that way. It just adds a time on the end of date. Prints like this: Your live roster has been edited. These changes concern Tauranga on Wed Apr 
21 2021 00:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time). Just would like to remove the time.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was also resolved. About your 3rd question, in that case, how about using `getDisplayValues` instead of `getValues`? But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.

Comment: That works a treat! Thanks again for all your help. I am very happy.

Comment: @Craig Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issues were resolved.

Answer (score 1):

> This sheet does not get edited, but rather changes occur through IMPORTRANGE.

No events get triggered when a formula result changes, so I do not think that you can get an automatic notification when values get updated in the imported data.

To make it work, you will have to use a trigger in the *source* spreadsheet rather than the *target* spreadsheet.